# SQL Exception when reading from ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

This is a DAO method that gets called when the user clicks the login button. `loginemail` and `pass` are the credentials entered by the user in the form.
The column name is `Password` in the database and the table name is `users`.

**The main problem is that ResultSet is not working as it should**, however the prepared statements with 'Insert' SQL query works nicely:

```
 public String authorize(String loginemail,String pass){
        Connection conn=null;
        boolean correctPassword=false;
        String pwd="default";
        PreparedStatement st=null;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URI,DB_USERNAME,DB_USERNAME);
        st=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT Password FROM users WHERE Email = ?");
        st.setString(1,loginemail);

        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery();


        if(rs.next())
        pwd=rs.getString("Password");    //(SQLException)error in this line
    }

    catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        return pwd;
    }
}
```

This is the method which registers users. It is working nicely, but when I introduce the ResultSet it gives me lemons.

```
public class UserDAO{
    static final  String DB_URI="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/social";
    static final String DB_USERNAME="root";
}
public boolean createUser(User user){

    Connection conn=null;
    boolean allGood=false;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URI,DB_USERNAME,DB_USERNAME);
        PreparedStatement ps=null;
        String userQ="INSERT INTO users (Name,Email,Gender,Password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        ps=conn.prepareStatement(userQ);
        ps.setString(1,user.getName());
        ps.setString(2,user.getEmailId());
        ps.setString(3,user.getGender());
        ps.setString(4,user.getPassword());

        ps.execute();
        conn.close();
        ps.close();
        allGood=true;
    }
    catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        return allGood;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post the exact exception you are getting, code looks fine.

Comment: Can you please post stack trace ?

Comment: worked after I replaced {if(rs.next())} by {while(rs.next())}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a Rookie mistake, replaced `if(rs.next())` by `while(rs.next())` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Remove "default" from String pwd and try this.

```
String pwd="";
```

Hope this works !!